# Visual Studio Recommending to Simplify Using Command

Tags: c#, visual-studio, using, c#-8.0

I've noticed since updating Visual Studio that it is now recommending to simplify my MySQL using statements.

It wants to change this:

```
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql_string, connection))
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();

                    business = new Business()
                    {
                        Id = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString()),
                        Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                    };

                    reader.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

Into this:

```
            using MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql_string, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                business = new Business()
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(reader["id"].ToString()),
                    Name = reader["name"].ToString(),
                };

                reader.Dispose();
            }
```

My question is, previously the code would be wrapped in brackets like so:

```
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql_string, connection))
            {

            }
```

Is the recommended suggestion by IntelliSense valid and won't cause any leaks?

Comment: This is a new way to declare using blocks available in c#8 (vs 2019) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

Comment: Its correct and reader needs wrapped as well.

Comment: Does reader need to be wrapped if I'm disposing of it?

Comment: @ScottC If an exception happens before you dispose, then you don't dispose because you are not using dispose in a finally block of a try/finally. Or if its `HasRows` property is false.

Comment: You should declare your reader as `using MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();` to make sure it is always disposed, too (and remove the explicit call to `reader.Dispose();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BradleyGrainger - is this the same with anything when using the using command? Calling .Dispose(); becomes redundant for everything?

Comment: @ScottC Yes, as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement , using the `using` statement or declaration is equivalent to calling `x.Dispose()` (in a `finally` block). `using` simplifies this code pattern for you and lets you know that the object will always be disposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a Using Declaration.

> A using declaration is a variable declaration preceded by the using keyword. It tells the compiler that the variable being declared should be disposed at the end of the enclosing scope.

As long as you need the using variable in the same scope suggested by the compiler, it should not be a problem.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations